# WebRequests are slow (taking 4 seconds) how do I speed them up?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest, performance

I'm doing a web request that is too slow. It takes around 3.2 seconds to GetResponseStream() and .8 seconds to ReadToEnd()

If I run the same request in a web browser I get a response in less than a second... I'm wondering what I can do to speed up the request and what might cause it to be slow?

Based on other questions I saw here, I disabled the proxy in app.config + enabled max connections, just in case (it's still slow). The section I added was:

```
 <system.net>
<defaultProxy enabled="false">
  <proxy/>
  <bypasslist/>
  <module/>
</defaultProxy>
<connectionManagement>
  <add address="*" maxconnection="65000" />
</connectionManagement>
```

Here's a screenshot of what the code looks like and what is slow:

[image]

I'd appreciate any help... 4-8 seconds is way too long for a user to wait for an ajax request to complete.

Thanks!

Comment: (Not that it's going to change the response time any, but why are you re-throwing what you just caught in the exception?)

Comment: Are you sure the browser isn't just caching it? Still, interesting question!

Comment: Well this method is from a library and I didn't change that part because the thrown errors are logged.

Comment: @Maxim Good point... I'll try with a request I know is not cached yet. But I'm pretty sure the tests I made weren't cached.

Comment: Regarding the throw: Michael wanted to know if you are sure that you want to use "throw ex" instead of "throw" and if you know the implications. Not helpful for your problem, but you should read about it maybe.

Comment: @Benjamin: It is a question in it's own right ... but `throw` throws the exception without modification, while `throw ex` resets the call stack to the current method, i.e. it looks as it occurred here and not in a subordinate method.

Comment: dangerous for you to have maxconnections at 65000, hopefully this was just something you did while playing around.

Comment: Are you sure the debugging / profiling hasn't significantly slowed things down?

Answer (score 4):

The line

```
responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
```

does 3 things at once:

1. It gets the response from the data.
2. It gets the response stream from the WebResponse object.
3. It opens the stream.

To improve timing analysis, and therefore understand where the bottleneck is, you first should recode the section to seperate the tasks.

```
HttpWebResponse response = WebRequest.GetResponse();
Stream s = response.GetResponseStream();
reader = new StreamReader(s);
```

In the `finally` block you just have to close the reader, as this also closes the underlying stream. Instead of explicitly closing the stream you could consider using an `using` block for the reader.

```
using (Stream s = response.GetResponseStream()) {
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(s);
    responseData = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I know that this is not a solution but maybe it provides a bit more insight as to where the time is lost.

A final suggestion, consider using asynchroneous execution to reduce the duration of the execution as perceived by the user.